# Does Google Play Store automatically updates apps automatically?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-min-sdk, targetsdkversion

If my App has minSDKVersion = 16 and TargetSDKVersion = 28, then will Google somehow upgrade my App to work with devices which use sdk version greater than 28?

And if the same is true for all future versions of SDK then if I dont update my app meanwhile?

Please excuse me as my English is not good. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google never ever updates your apps for the latest SDK, you have to do it yourself and publish again. I know its a pain when google play console frequently changes requirements to support certain Target API Level but its the pain you have to endure. TargetSDKVersion is the last SDK / API which your app will support.

Answer (score 3):

No, you will need to do an update by changing your targetSDK from your build.gradle file, then make the required changes in your code to work with that API level and you can upload an update.

The Playstore will not update it automatically, that's why it's called targetSDKVersion, it will just be available from SDK 16 until the target one, 28.